# Vim - Quit/Close Netrw without selecting any file

Tags: vim, netrw

My question is fairly simple, still I can't find the answer anywhere : 
In Vim, how can I close Netrw explorer without actually selecting a file? 
What keystroke should I hit to close the explorer and go back to the currently opened file?

So far, I have to select the currently opened file from within Netrw if I want to get back to it, which happens to be impossible if I haven't saved it yet.

I may add that I RTFM, and do know the `:h netrw` command ;)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `<c-6>`/`<c-^>` to go back to the previous buffer. See `:h CTRL-6`.

Pro-tip: use `:Rex` to *resume* exploring. See `:h :Rex`

Comment: Many thanks. 
On my machine, this diminishes the font size of my Terminal though. Probably some Gnome 3 settings, or Fedora's. 

Using `:b#` did the tricks of going back to the previous buffer ;) Many thanks !

Comment: After looking at the help entry, I had to do `<c-^>` (i.e. `<c-S-6>`) for this to work. (OSX Terminal.app)

Comment: Is there a way to assign :Explore to F3, and then use the same key to close the explorer? Like NerdTreeToggle.

Answer (score 32):

Vim by default, without plugins etc., should treat netrw windows like buffers (without listing it like one (:ls or :buffer).
Try:

```
:bd
:bdelete
```

or

```
:bw
:bwipe
```

Peculiar way Vim did not list the netrw windows as buffer, but close it like one, and went back to former buffer/file.

Comment: Hmmm... actually, if I am using several windows, this will close the current windows I am using, which is bad...

Comment: @AlexandreBourlier: then you don't want to close/quit netrw.  You want something in its stead.  You probably need to upgrade netrw to get :Rex working.  Other than that, simply  :e whatever-file-you-want.  If you want a new but empty buffer, then use :enew .

Comment: Thanks this is great !!! Also, actually, the buffer exists, but is hidden. Try `:ls!` and you will see it appearing in the list :) ... And `bd<number>` with the opened netrw directory buffer number will do the trick as well, if for any reson you switched buffers and let some netrw buffers open.

Comment: Sorry it should be `:bd<number>` in my precedent comment (cannot edit anymore)

Comment: As @Joel.O says, you may check which buffer is with `:buffers` and then delete it with `:bd<number>` (I needed to use `:bw`)

Answer (score 7):

With v153 of netrw, one may use :Rex to return to the netrw buffer; it will *also* permit you to return to the file being edited prior to editing a directory.  (see http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW for the latest netrw).

Comment: Thanks for this contribution; However I tried and it is not working for me. Entering `:Rex` from Netrw just doesn't do anything

Comment: What version of netrw are you using?  netrw v154b may be found on http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW .

Comment: @AlexandreBourlier is that because your previous buffer was a [NO NAME] ? :Rex only returns if you were in a named buffer, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Create the below function:

```
function! s:close_explorer_buffers()
    for i in range(1, bufnr('$'))
        if getbufvar(i, '&filetype') == "netrw"
            silent exe 'bdelete! ' . i
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

Add mapping:

```
nnoremap <C-e><C-x> :call <sid>close_explorer_buffers()<cr>
```

Comment: For the record, mapping this to `QuitPre` was what I needed to prevent a `<C-Tab>`-collapsed `:Lexplore` from turning `:q :q` into `:q :q :q` in the case of `E173: ... more files to edit`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and followed Peter Rincker's suggestion of going to the alternate file.

I used the following remapping to make this easier

`map <leader><leader>. <C-^>`

Since my leader is `,`, I have the keystrokes `,,.` for alternate file, which leaves the `netrw` file explorer thing (which I don't know anything else about at this point).

Answer (score -1):

I find that using `:exit` closes the `netrw` buffer and returns to the previous buffer.

Comment: This is totally wrong. It closes the window/split, if there's only one window, it quits Vim.